# Unable to Use useState in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

**Description**:

I am experiencing an issue when trying to use the useState hook in Next.js 13. When attempting to use useState, I receive the following error message:

**Steps to Reproduce**:

Create a Next.js 13 project.
Attempt to use the useState hook in a functional component.
Observe the error message mentioned above.

**Expected Behavior**:

I expect to be able to use the useState hook in a Next.js 13 project without encountering any errors.

**Actual Behavior**:

I receive the "Invalid hook call" error when trying to use the useState hook, despite using it correctly within a functional component.

```
"use client"

import { Box, Button, Input, Text } from '@/components'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
    const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState<boolean>(false)

    return (
        <Box className='w-screen h-screen'>
            <Box className='w-1/2 h-full p-24 pt-12 flex-col justify-around'>
                <Text className='font-black text-3xl'>TOOTO ADMIN</Text>
                <Box className='flex-col space-y-6' >
                    <Text className='text-3xl' >Welcome back!</Text>
                    <Text>Enter your Credentials to access your account</Text>
                    <Box className='flex-col' >
                        <Text>Email address</Text>
                        <Input placeholder='Enter your email' width={'100%'} height={'40px'} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box className='flex-col' >
                        <Box className='justify-between' >
                            <Text>Password</Text>
                            <Text className='text-[#82A957] text-xs underline cursor-pointer'>forgot password</Text>
                        </Box>
                        <Input placeholder='Enter your password' width={'100%'} height={'40px'} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box className='flex' >
                        <Box onClick={() => setRememberMe(!rememberMe)} className='w-auto space-x-1.5 cursor-pointer' >
                            <Image src={rememberMe ? "/remember-me-icon-checked.svg" : "/remember-me-icon.svg"} alt="remember me icon" width={9} height={10} />
                            <Text className='text-xs' >Remember me</Text>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                    <Button width={`100%`} height={`32px`} className={`flex rounded-lg justify-center items-center`}>
                        <Text className='text-default_white font-bold text-sm'>Login</Text>
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box className='w-1/2 h-full'>
                <Image src='/login-background.jpg' alt='login-background'
                    className='w-full h-full rounded-l-3xl'
                    width={782}
                    height={1042} />
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

[image: error message on my terminal]

[image: error message on my localhost]

I expected that using the useState hook within a functional component in a Next.js 13 project would work as intended without any errors.

Comment: Can you add your package.json file to the question? I suppose you are  mismatching the react version used by the next js.